# Editing python script/executable

Tags: python, serial-port, executable, py2exe, pyserial

I have a working python program that sets IP/gateway/broadcast addresses for different devices using pySerial.

The basic idea would be that the user enters the addresses themselves and the program does the rest

```
IP = 'x.x.x.x'
broadcast = 'x.x.x.x'
gateway = 'x.x.x.x'
```

My initial thought was just to have the user open up the python program and change the addresses to whatever they want and then run it, but I came into a few problems

1. That's probably not the best practice to let the user do that
2. The user needs python installed
3. If I create an executable from my current code, the user won't be able to change the addresses to what they want

What would be the best way to allow users to enter their own addresses? The point of this script was to automate a proccess so getting user input didn't really make sense for me to do

Comment: There are lots of options. Common ones include reading a configuration file or accepting command line arguments.  For both solutions there are lots of modules from which you can choose, including a few that are in the standard library.

Comment: You can use raw_input() function for example. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible ways to do this, although the user will still need Python in some form to run your application. Having said that, if you package your application with a tool such as [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), it will package a minimal Python interpreter so that the user does not have to install it separately.

1. Use a configuration file that the script reads the addresses from.
2. Pass the addresses as arguments on the command line.
3. Ask a network service for the addresses.

Comment: @MorganThrapp, It seems we do not disagree about the necessity of the interpreter. Yes, I was aware that you could package it, but I guess I misinterpreted the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely read OP's main concern as "I want to give this program to someone who doesn't have Python installed". It seems unlikely that they're opposed to there being a copy of Python already there. Thought I could easily be wrong.